# Create line chart with multiple lines per year

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, linechart, ggplotly

I want to create a line chart with multiple lines per `acquiYear`, where the x-axis should represent the `month` and the y-axis the `nrOrders`.

My data table looks like this:

```
structure(list(delivYear = c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018"
), acquiYear = c("2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018"), quater = c("Q1", 
"Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", 
"Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", 
"Q4", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", 
"Q4", "Q4", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", 
"Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4"), month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
"May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", 
"Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
"May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), nrOrders = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "1", "1", "2", "0", "2", "4", "5", "3", "7", "3", "5", "4", 
"3", "7", "8", "7", "2", "24", "16", "33", "9", "27", "16", "10", 
"27", "9", "31", "35", "11", "11", "25", "15", "18", "19", "19", 
"8", "27", "34", "43", "51", "0", "11", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "4", "5", "1", "0"), eur = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "180", "8760", "17760", "0", "6730", "5354", "2840", 
"22190", "29210", "8725", "7226", "12500", "2090", "13780", "21434", 
"15719", "29000", "112366", "38148", "125900", "10285", "54281", 
"23777", "111512", "76907", "18306", "124393", "103220", "8890", 
"52082", "119095", "28482", "62841", "54356", "54119", "42999", 
"112459", "169798", "123808", "504226", "0", "55336", "3017", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "15880", "1844", "252", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

How can I create a chart with multiple lines per year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible easy way using `ggplot2`

```r
library("ggplot2")
df$nrOrders <- as.numeric(df$nrOrders) 
df$month = factor(df$month, levels = month.abb) ## Order the months
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=month, y=nrOrders, group= acquiYear)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = acquiYear)) +
  geom_point()
```

Could also be coded directly as follow :

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(month, levels = month.abb), y=as.numeric(nrOrders), group= acquiYear)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = acquiYear)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("month")
```

I you want an histogram, you can do it as follow:

```r
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(month, levels = month.abb), y=as.numeric(nrOrders), fill= acquiYear)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge', linewidth = 1) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("month") +
  ylab("nrOrders")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey10", "grey20", "grey30", "grey40", "grey50"))
```

I however, do not think that an histogram is appropriate for such data.

Comment: Using your code gives me a plot, but here the y- and x-axis is not ordered from 0 to max(nrOrders) and Jan-Dec. How can we fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited my code.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!! If I want to create a histogramm instead of the line chart. How would I do this? Replace ``geom_line()`` by ``geom_histogram()`` is not enough.